# Python, прервать условие IF

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, if

Всем привет. Я делаю парсер и на сайте, где проходит авторизация иногда появляется кнопка 'Выход'. Мне нужно написать функцию, которая будет автоматически нажимать на кнопку 'Выход', но проблема в том, что кнопка появляется через раз и функция нажатия также отрабатывает через раз, попутно выдавая ошибку. Я делал через условие IF, мол если видна кнопка, то нажимай, но когда её не видно, то вылезает ошибка и парсер не отрабатывает. Что в итоге писать в Else? Break и continue не отрабатывают без цикла for

```
x = WebDriverWait(self._browser, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(*локатор*)))
if x:
   x.click()
```

Comment: Фрагмент кода то приведите, иначе помочь будет трудно

Comment: Добавил код функции

Comment: Хорошо бы еще ошибку, которая у вас возникает, чтобы я мог дополнить свой ответ

Comment: Ошибка "NoSuchElementException", программа не может найти вебэлемент. Там получается идёт заполнение формы, но для начала заполнения нужно найти кнопку 'Авторизоваться', но предшествующая кнопка 'Выход' не находится и из-за этого программа не запускается

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос, пока не совсем понятно где что происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А Вы зацепитесь за текст этой кнопки )

```
try:
    if x.text == 'Выход':
        x.click()
except Exception:
    pass
```

Ниже ответ тоже рабочий

Comment: Это самый странный способ решения проблемы, который я видел, но он работает) 
Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

При помощи `if x:` не получится обойти ошибку, потому что она возникает раньше, в момент работы парсера - строка `x = WebDriverWait(...)`.

Для решения проблемы достаточно обернуть код в блок `try/except` и обработать исключение `NoSuchElementException`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    x = WebDriverWait(self._browser, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(*локатор*))
    x.click()   
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло - при отсутствии кнопки, программа также падает

Comment: @H8Umate значит вы не тот блок кода предоставили, в котором возникает ошибка, потому что `try/except` ловит все исключения, и не дает программе упасть

Comment: Странно. Если убрать этот блок и нажимать кнопку 'Выход' самому, то программа проходит успешно и без ошибок, но с этим блоком она перестает работать

Comment: @H8Umate после того, как вы добавили тип исключения я нашел аналогичный вопрос на англоязычной версии sof, вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022658/selenium-python-handling-no-such-element-exception), но решение в этом вопросе совпадает с моим, так что возможно вы делаете что-то не так

Comment: "Если за это время элемент не найден, генерируется исключение TimeoutException" https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: @СергейКох изучите контекст вопроса, прежде чем писать комментарии.

Comment: Прежде чем давать ответ, пожалуйста, проверяйте его на любом демо-сайте.